# StyleCop Spelling Rules and Hyperlinks

Tags: visual-studio, coding-style, stylecop

Is there a way to disable StyleCop spell-check for hyperlinks?  I really like the rule feature, but it's complaining about misspelled words in a lot of my hyperlinks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found 2 possible workarounds for this:

**1) Attempt to CamelCase your hyperlinks.**

I have a couple of issues with this approach.  First off, I like all my hyperlinks to be
    lowercase, if possible; I'm OCD about it.  Second (and more
    importantly), case matters on some hyperlinks.  So doing this to get past the
    style error, but potentially breaks your hyperlinks.

**2) Throw your hyperlinks inside a `<see href=""/>` tag.**

I have found that StyleCop will not attempt to enforce it's spell check feature in this case.

Comment: The <see href> tag was a quick and helpful tip!

Comment: Note: As of StyleCop 4.7.49 "https" is still treated as error.